# Smd Component identification

Tags: identification, components, surface-mount

I was creating schematic from  a pcb but could not understand what the component in the image is for.[image][image]

The name written on the component is L386. At first i thought that it is a voltage regulator like 1117 but when i checked it the left pin and the middle pin are shorted with resistor placed above it. Then i checked , maybe it was lm317 in sot223 package but such high value of resistor is present so it was ruled out. The resistor that is present on the other side and is of 640K

Comment: 640 kohms is an unusual value.

Comment: Could it say 1386 instead of L386?  Would it make sense to be a PNP transistor (2SB1386)?  Since it is marked S1, which usually means switch, maybe they are using a PNP to do some switching?

Comment: @Andy aka 4 its quite an unusual value. I could also not determine why it is being used here.

Comment: @evildemonic It is written L there. I also gave a thought about it that it might be a switch but a 640K resistor between its 2 pins is quite unusual.